# How can I use Windows command line to delete all files in a particular directory that were created on a specific date?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash-scripting

I accidentally blew up a tarball on my PC and now have something like 2 million unwanted files in my Documents folder. Windows Explorer crashes if I try to use it to view the contents of that folder, so now I'm trying to write a line of code I can use in the command line to kill everything in the Documents folder that was created on that date.

I've found some answers on StackOverflow that show how to do this for files older than a certain age (e.g., 10 days or older), but not for a single, specific date, and this is a programming language and syntax I don't know.

What should that line of code say?

Comment: Are there subfolders you need to search too,, or all the files directly inside the Documents folder?

Comment: Is this perhaps the SO article you found? PowerShell is the normal Windows shell these days: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822013/get-list-of-files-with-a-specific-date-range This has pretty much the exact answer to your question.

Comment: @music2myear all directly in the Documents folder

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822013/get-list-of-files-with-a-specific-date-range

PowerShell is where you need to do this. PowerShell is the standard shell for windows now.

**Step 1:** Open a PowerShell window. Because you're deleting things in your own Documents folder you should not need to run it as administrator, but if it doesn't work, you may try a second time after opening PowerShell as administrator.

**Step 2:** Run this command to list all the files you are going to delete. This is the entire command without the Delete part:

```
Get-ChildItem <path to your documents folder> | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -like "04/20/2023 *"}
```

I've found this syntax does the best job returning results. If you have a single-digit day or month, precede it with a "0" to make sure it is two digits long.

You could pipe this out to a file as well, if you wish to manually review the list before deleting:

```
Get-ChildItem <path to your documents folder> | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -like "04/20/2023 *"} | export-csv "C:\temp\filesToDelete.csv"
```

**Step 3:** Once you've confirmed this is the list of files that you want to delete, run the same command one more time, but with the delete bit added on:

```
Get-ChildItem <path to your documents folder> | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -like "04/20/2023 *"} | Remove-Item
```

If you get errors due to hidden or read-only files, add the `-Force` argument to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

Comment: +1 for doing this stepwise, to be safe. BTW, not sure if this might place file in Recycle Bin... if so, turn off Recycle Bin, lest this operation be *slow* and fail when Bin fills.

Comment: In `04/20/2023` `20` is definitely not the month, so the format must be `mm/dd/yyyy`. Will this format work everywhere? Or should users adjust it to their locale and settings? E.g. I acknowledge that `dd/mm/yyyy` format is used in some countries. In other words: if I specify `01/02/2023`, can I be sure it's Jan 02 and not Feb 01, *regardless of my locale and/or other settings*?

Comment: I prefer the only right format, yyyy/mm/dd, but I believe this setting may be localized. This is one reason I specified doing the test run first to see WHAT will be passed to the delete function.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: `Remove-Item` deletes items, it doesn't move them to the **Recycle Bin**. To do that in**PowerShell**, you have to use the `shell.application` com object..

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I use Windows command line to delete all files in a particular directory that were created on a specific date?*
>
> ```bash
> cd /d "%UserProfile%\Documents\" & @for /f tokens^=*delims^= %G in ('2^>nul dir /a:-d /b /o:d ".\*.*"')do @wmic datafile where "name='%cd:\=\\%\\%~nxG'" get creationdate /format:xml | findstr "VALUE.*20230607" >nul && @del /q /f /a: ".\%~nxG"
> ```

---

For **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** file:

```bash
@echo off && setlocal

chDir /d "%UserProfile%\Documents\"

for /f tokens^=*delims^= %%G in =;(
   '2^>nul dir /a:-d /b /o:d ".\*.*"
   ')do call %:^) "%cd:\=\\%\\%%~nxG"

%:^) 
if "%~1" == "" endlocal && goto :eOf
for /f "usebackqtokens=4delims=<>" %%i in (`
     wmic datafile where "name='%~1'" get creationdate /format:xml ^| findstr "VALUE.*20230607"
    `)do del /q /f /a: "%~1" & exit /b
```

---

---

**1.** Enter your folder, preferably replace "`%UserProfile%\Documents`" with a full path:

```bash
chDir /d "C:\Users\ulfelder\Documents"
```

---

**2.** List your files excluding folders (`/a-d`) in a for /f loop

```bash
for /f tokens^=*delims^= %%G in ('2^>nul dir /a:-d /b /o:d ".\*.*"')do ...
```

---

**3.** Use `Wmic datafile where "name='x'"` to get creation date of each file in looping:

```bash
...)do wmic datafile where "name='%~1'" get creationdate /format:xml
```

---

**4.** Redirect `wmic` output to `findstr` to match against relevant date `"...20230607"`:

```
wmic ... get ... | findstr "VALUE.*20230607"
```

- **Obs.1:** Change the date in use in the example to the date you want to select for the selection criteria of the files you want to delete, obeying the layout ***YYYYMMDD*** (date layout 20230607) in:

```
 wmic ... get ... | findstr "VALUE.*20230607"
```

- **Obs.2:**  The strings `20230607` applies to the date day **07** (seven) of the month **06** (June) of the year 2023, to also assign a specific time like: **11**.pm and **22** minutes, use yyyymmdd***HHMM***:

```
wmic ... get ... | findstr "VALUE.*202306071123"
```

- **Obs.3:** The `wmic` retunr the date and time in format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.milliseconds[+/-]GMT_Offset_in_minutes.`][13](https://mivilisnet.wordpress.com/2019/03/28/current-date-and-time-using-wmic/#:%7E:text=As%20you%20can%20see%2C%20the,Year%20%3D%202019)***

```
for /f ...(`wmic datafile where "name='path\\file'" get creationdate ...| findstr "VALUE.*strong>202306071122"`)do ...
2023060705112213.021224-180

::----------------------------------------------
:: WMIC Retunrs:  Means:
::----------------------------------------------
::         Year = 2023
::        Month = 06
::          Day = 07
::        Hours = 11
::      Minutes = 22
::      Seconds = 13
:: Milliseconds = 021224
::   GMT_offset = -180 minutes 
::                 Greenwich Mean Time (GMT-3)
::                 Brasilia Time Zone
::----------------------------------------------
```

---

**5.** Omit the the output of `findstr` with `>nul` , and if the relevant date matches the date of the file obtained from the file, the `&&` operator (`return 0`) will execute the `del` command deleting the file in a loop:

```
... findstr "VALUE.*20230607" >nul && del /q /f /a: "%~1"
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`CD /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [`Call /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`Del /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Where does **`GOTO :EOF`** return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: I feel like it should be obvious - but what does Obs. mean in this context?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thx, but im here and still editing..

Comment: Still unclear. Observation? Object? Objection?

Comment: I think it is "Observation".

Comment: Yes! Observation == Obs.